# Calling an Ajax function based on button class name click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created several image buttons in php. I have assigned a common class to all of them. When I call a jquery function based on button class name click. This works fine but when I try calling an ajax function it doesn't work. There is no error seen.

PHP to create a button

```
function printpic($name, $picpath, $category, $pic)
{  
    $style = " margin=0px; background-color=transparent; border=none;";
    //$functionname= "selectedpic(this.id)";
    $functionname= "myCall(this.id);";
    $styleimage = "HEIGHT= 120  WIDTH= 120  BORDER=0";
    $eventimage1= "zoomin(this)";
    $eventimage2= "zoomout(this)";
    $btnclass="btnclass";   
    $j=0;
    $spa=0;
    $i=0;
    for($k=0; $k<4; $k++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j=0; $j<4; $j++)
        {   
            echo"<td>"; 
            $btn= "btn".$category[$i];
            echo "<span id='" . $spa. "'>";
            echo "<button name='" . $btn. "'
            margin ='".$style."' 
            class='".$btnclass."'
            onClick='".$functionname."'
            >";

            echo "<img src='". $picpath[$i]."/".$name[$i]."' 
            id ='".$pic[$i]."'
            alt ='".$name[$i]."'
            .$styleimage.
            onMouseMove='".$eventimage1."'
            onMouseOut='".$eventimage2."'

            >";
            echo "</button >";
            $spa++;
            echo"</span>";
            echo"</td>"; 
            $i++;
        } // wfor

    echo "</tr>";
           }// for
         }      // end function
        ?>
```

Jquery + Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.btnclass').click(function() {

event = event || window.event; 
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; 
var id = target.id;
var but = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.name;
var datastring = '&id='+ id;

$.ajax({

         url: "indexverification.php",
         type: "POST",          
         data: datastring,
         success: function(responseText) { // get the response
         if(responseText == 1) { alert ("hi");}
         else { alert (datastring); }

        } // end success            
        }); // ajax end



});
```

});

indexverification.php

```
<?php
  session_start();      
  $picno=$_SESSION['picno']; // picno from db
  $answer=$_SESSION['answer']; // answer from db
  $id=$_POST['id']; // id of picture clicked
  $ans=$_SESSION['ans']; // answer type


  if (($id==$picno) && ($answer==$ans))
 {
    echo '1';
 }

 else 
{
    echo '2';   
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML of a created <span> element that printpic($name, $picpath, $category, $pic) creates as an example? To me, it looks like your syntax is correct for the ajax call. Are you getting the alerted "datastring" or are you not even making it that far?

Comment: are u getting any error in console log?

Comment: @DustinCochran yes i am able to alert the datastring. After that it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Prashant no error log :-(

Comment: Nothing is showing up in your error log as I believe all your code is right. Nothing should happen after the alert as there is nothing left to trigger. Due to you receiving your datastring alert means (($id==$picno) && ($answer==$ans)) are not equal and returns '2'.

You need to check your values in indexverification.php to make sure they are what you expect them to be. Use "print_r($_SESSION)" and "print_r($_POST)" and make sure it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Suppose I should mention you will need to change your alert(datastring) to alert(responseText) so you can see the printed out values.

Comment: @DustinCochran I am unable to get any alter mesages.

Comment: So when you do - if(responseText == 1) { alert ("hi");} else { alert (datastring); } - you can get it to alert(datastring), but if you change alert(datastring) to alert(responseText) you don't get it?

Comment: Sorry it doesnt alert anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
//AJAX request
$.ajax({
     url: "indexverification.php",
     type: "POST",          
     data: datastring,      
})
//Success action
.success(function( html ) {
    if(responseText == 1) { alert ("hi");}
    else { alert (datastring); };
}) 
//Error action
.fail(function() {
    alert("Request failed.");
});
```

Comment: dude your code is right....but above code is also right. your can write ajax() function multiple ways.